# Placing mat-icons inside a select in Angular 6

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular6

I would like to place mat-icons inside a select. The idea is to have all available fruit statuses in the select and instead showing their names(or ids), show their mat-icon representation. The select is working as expected, although I can't seem to replace the text with icons.

What I've tried:

-> replacing the mat-icon with a simple span with font awesome class, presented here:

[Material select with material-icons issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470318/material-select-with-material-icons-issue)

-> playing around with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746997/angular-material-maticon-in-matselect) answer, but using mat-select instead of select breaks the whole div (it is not working as expected, not able to select anything, no options, or even select the trigger).

My code (one version):

```
    <select [(ngModel)]="fruits.status_id">
        <option *ngFor="let stat of statuses" [value]="stat.id">
            <div>
                <span class="fa fa-lock" *ngIf="stat.id === 1"></span>
                <span class="fa fa-lock-open" *ngIf="stat.id === 2"></span>
            </div>
        </option>
    </select>
```

Another version:

```
    <select [(ngModel)]="fruits.status_id">
        <option *ngFor="let stat of statuses" [value]="stat.id">
                <span *ngIf="stat.id === 1"><mat-icon>lock</mat-icon></span>
                <span *ngIf="stat.id === 2"><mat-icon>open_lock</mat-icon></span>
        </option>
    </select>
```

Being that none of them work, I'd appreciate any help on this matter. Thank you!

*Additional info*

When used with font awesome, I get empty select options, no errors, but also no icons.

When using mat-icons, the "icon" part get completely ignored, with the select options showing the text (names) of the icons.

And in case it could be a question, I *need* to use something like select because there might be more statuses in the future

*Edit:* 
I use both types of icons(mat and FA) in the same app in other places, and they are behaving as expected, so all the imports for them are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been solved by using everything "mat-".

Here's the code that works, for anyone that's having the same or a similar issue:

```
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="fruits.status_id">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let stat of statuses" [value]="stat.id">
            <mat-icon *ngIf="stat.status_name === 'opened'">lock_open</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="stat.status_name === 'closed'">lock</mat-icon>
        </mat-option>
        <mat-select-trigger>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="getStatusName(fruits.status_id) === 'opened'">lock_open</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="getStatusName(fruits.status_id) === 'closed'">lock</mat-icon>
        </mat-select-trigger>
    </mat-select>
```